# Cannot access ports on MacOSX host from within docker container

Tags: curl, docker, localhost, port

These were the steps I took:

**Prework:**

First:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

Then, I created a container with the following Dockerfile:

`FROM centos:latest`

Nothing else — just a copy of CentOS. I built the container:

```
docker build -t mycontainer .
```

And run it:

```
docker run -it --net="host" --name="test" -p 9200:9200 mycontainer
```

**Problem:** When I go inside the container and try to access a service running on MacOSX (such as a simple webserver or a local elasticsearch), I get:

```
curl localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused
```

I get the same error from within my docker vm (`docker-machine ssh default`).

I tried port forwarding in virtualbox, setting 9200 to 9200 — but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot connect from a docker container to a port on your host with localhost:port (unless you run your container with `--net="host"` )

You need to specify the ip address of your host to connect.

Please check for the IP on the host:

```
dude-server:stackoverflow cwoehrle$ ping $(hostname)
PING dude-server (192.168.1.169): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.169: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.169: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
```

In the container (use your ip respectively):

```
root@8975fada1ac3:/# nc 192.168.1.169 9200
```

Edited:
To connect to your host ports on a mac you can use the default gateway address 10.0.2.2, e.g. `nc 10.0.2.2 9200`

Comment: I used `--net="host"`, but I found out that I can connect to the VM but not MacOSX. So, I need to get a two-sided network from the VM to my MacOSX?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the --net="host" part. Yes, you can set network to NAT in virtualbox to access the ports of your host. Still I wasn´t able to connect to  localhost:port but had to use `nc 10.0.2.2 9200` to connect to the host port (10.0.2.2 is the default gateway for nat connections)

Comment: Wow, now that is why I love StackOverflow. I did not have to use `nc` and not even the `--net="host"`. My elasticsearch instance responded right out of the box using `curl 10.0.2.2:9200` from within the container. How could I have known that? (honest question: is 10.0.2.2 common knowledge?)

Comment: I wonder if this has changed since Jan 2016. 10.0.2.2 can't be pinged or otherwise accessed from within a container on my Mac. However, 192.168.65.2 does work. The default network setup must have changed. UPDATE: Researching, Docker provides a host alias for this: host.docker.internal - no need to hard-code an IP.

Answer (score 0):

From within the container, simply reference:

```
host.docker.internal
```

So, your curl command would be:

```
curl http://host.docker.internal:9200
```